# Why is spring not injecting using generic qualifiers?

Tags: java, spring, generics

this is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
class Factories {

    @Bean
    Collection<Log> logs() {
        List<Log> logs = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) { // gross example code
            Log log = new Log();
            log.setEntry( RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic( 10 ) );
            logs.add( log );
        }
        return logs;
    }
}
```

and here's how I'm trying to autowire it

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class LogService {

    private final LogRepository repository;
    private final ObjectFactory<Instant> now;
    private final Collection<Log> logs;

    @Autowired
    LogService( final LogRepository repository, final ObjectFactory<Instant> now, final Collection<Log> logs ) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.now = now;
        this.logs = logs;
    }
```

but I get this exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xenoterracide.example.log.Log] found for dependency [collection of com.xenoterracide.example.log.Log]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1024)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 24 more
```

[according to the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-generics-as-qualifiers) I think this should work. [Here's my full code in case you need it](https://bitbucket.org/xenoterracide/modern-spring-web-development/src/44d3ed2f7fd32e56d1e880b104bd9f8823615fd0/src/main/java/com/xenoterracide/example/?at=master). Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: Don't create `Log` beans as collection. Instead, create each `Log` with its own `@Bean` annotation. The `Collection<Log>` injection should work.

Comment: @ajb [They are](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType--) and Spring does.

Comment: I didn't know that... guess I took "type erasure" too seriously...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `@Autowired` a `List<Something>`, Spring will look for as many `Something` beans as you have defined in your `ApplicationContext` and attempt to autowire them all into the target. [The documentation states](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, **beans that are
>   themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected
>   through `@Autowired`**, because type matching is not properly applicable
>   to them. Use `@Resource` for such beans, referring to the specific
>   collection or map bean by unique name.

In your case, you have

```
@Autowired
LogService(/* ... */ final Collection<Log> logs ) {
```

but no `Log` beans. So it complains

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xenoterracide.example.log.Log] found for dependency [collection of com.xenoterracide.example.log.Log]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

What you seem to want is a bean of type `Collection<Log>` injected directly. Spring can do this with the `javax.annotation.Resource` annotation. Unfortunately, that annotation doesn't work on constructors.

You'll need to either annotate your (changed to non-`final`) field or add a setter method and annotate that.

```
@Resource
private Collection<Log> logs;
```

or

```
@Resource
public void setLogs(Collection<Log> logs) {
    this.logs = logs;
}
```

Comment: curious, does `@Inject` behave the same way as `@Autowired` for this case?

Comment: @xenoterracide Yes, `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` handles both of those. `@Resource` is handled by a `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.